# Multi Stage with Zend Framework - where to configure/store form emails?

Tags: zend-framework

On our development servers, When we work with forms and we test them, normally we use our own emails so that, when we test, we can receive those results and see if it's all working.

When we change to production, we must change those emails to "production" emails.

Often, we tend to forget that, and not so uncommonly we are receiving data that we shouldn't and, at the same time, our production beneficiaries aren't receiving what they should.

**How can we deal with this, in a way that, according to the Environment variable definition, we can either have one email to be applied on our forms submissions, or another email?**

**Update - Important clarifications:**

1)

I'm not that concerned with status messages, or emails that we use while stress testing something odd, no bug notifications, nothing like that.

It's a much simple concept:
 - We have some subscription forms and a contact form. On the prod ENV that will correspond to two or three different emails. No more than that.

2)

Let's suppose we are extending Zend_Form for form creation and that, we have something among this lines (more or less):

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST')
->setPost(array(
'name'
=> 'Some Name',
'email'
=> 'contact@email.com',
'message'
=> "This is my test message."
));
$this->dispatch('/about/contact');
```

**Update 2:**

Can or should we have on my application.ini file something like:

```
[production]
contact.email.address = "trueemail@email.com"
contact.email.name = "John Stuart"

joinus.email.address = "anotheremail@email.com"
joinus.email.name = "Patricia Bill"


[development : production]
contact.email.address = "my@email.com"
contact.email.name = "Devname"

joinus.email.address = "my@email.com"
joinus.email.name = "Devname"
```

Or should we do this on another way ?

If we have like 10 different emails, this still is a laborious work and repetitive, because, if we have 10 forms, or **development environment email** will be repeated 10 times! :s

Another doubt that I have here is, once this is defined on the application.ini:

How can I call those emails address and names ?

What would be a acceptable way for doing it ?

Comment: please explain what are the emails for ? for example newsletter emails or "status" emails, or ... becouse it realy depends, if you have only a few emails to be used then they could be defined in application.ini, if for example there are newsletter emails saved in a db you could add a flag to them ( but not realy needed since you have different databases allready based on the environment ) so ... what are the emails used for exactly and i'm shure there is an easy way to achive this

Comment: @poelinca and all: I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: so application.ini define you're emails depending on the environment, at bootstrap define them or use Zend_Registry or set a class/object property ... and then just get the values where you need, this would work best if you have some testing emails setup so every developer has access to them, then from project to project the testing emails would remain the same ...

Comment: poelinca - Thanks. Can you please provide me a little example of the above? About if I should use bootstrap or Zend_Registry or set a class/object - to be honest, I'm not sure what to choose, since I unable to see the good and bad things of each of those. Care to provide an answer according to this and the stated on your previous comment? - Thanks a lot, really. ps- I can well create a solo email, and define that as a devemail so that all developers could test forms using it.

Comment: @poetinca and all: I've updated my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to answer without knowing how your application is structured, how the forms are created and where the recipient details come from. But can you not simply check the APPLICATION_ENV at the point where you set the email address?

```
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
    $email = 'yourtestemail@example.com'; // your test email address
} else {
    $email = 'normalemail@example.com'; // whatever the email should be
}
```

**Edit:** Since you implied you are creating your forms by extending Zend_Form, how about adding a base class for your contact forms which contains the logic I have above? Something like this:

```
class Yourapp_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_recipientEmail;

    public function setRecipientEmail($email)
    {
        $this->_recipientEmail = $email;
    }

    public function getRecipientEmail()
    {
        if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'develpoment') {
            return 'yourtestemail@example.com';
        } else {
            return $this->_recipientEmail;
        }
    }
}
```

you'd then use it in a similar way to how you currently use Zend_Form, so something like:

```
class Yourapp_Contact_Form extends Yourapp_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement([...]);
        $this->setRecipientEmail('foo@example.com'); // <-- production email address
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tim Fountain: I have added more details on my question. I believe that your answer as it is, will force me to search for "where have I defined those emails again?". Also, Boris Guéry as a point about hard coding that, instead of use something more general as intended here.

Comment: I think you have the "where have I defined those emails again?" problem whatever you do, as you'll have to change existing code to use whatever new solution you adopt. I've extended my answer with a better example, this still checks APPLICATION_ENV but only does so in one place.

Comment: @Tim Fountain - That seems nice. However, and despite the fact that that will work, it may be the case that we may need, not only a contact form, but also a "register form", and a "join us" form... all on the same application. And, taking your code, that will imply a creating of Yourapp_Contact_Form and all other forms, that sure needed to be there, but, on each of those, I also need to check the APPLICATAION_ENV - can't we have a more dry approach ? Please advice. :)

Comment: I think the names I chose for the classes in my example confused things a little, I've tweaked those. I meant you would extend the class you create (now Yourapp_Form in my example above) for any forms that need to email out, not define the same methods in each form class.

Comment: I see! Ok. Thanks makes sense. :) Btw, I believe what I want to accomplish here, should be a very common thing among zend developers no? If not, perhaps I'm missing a key workflow that I need to grasp? Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim: I have accepted your answer. For my own records however, I'm still not convinced if that's the best approach we may have. Perhaps "application resource" could help us here... :?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand what you want, however, if what you are looking for is a way to handle some logic to happen depending on your environment, here is a solution.

Write a Service, which you load anywhere (prod, dev, etc.). This service will take in charge of checking whether it should notify you or not depending on your `APPLICATION_ENV`.

The main advantage using a Service against an hard-coded if condition is to allow you to don't care about the availability of your method or not.

The component would act in a similar way to `Zend_Log`, and maybe, this component may fit your need better, depending on your use case.

With `Zend_Log`, you can set a priority to filter depending on your `APPLICATION_ENV` in your `config.ini`.

```
[development]
resources.log.stream.filterName = "Priority"
resources.log.stream.filterParams.priority = Zend_Log::DEBUG
[production]
resources.log.stream.filterName = "Priority"
resources.log.stream.filterParams.priority = Zend_Log::DEBUG
```

`Zend_Log` provides several so-called writters, which are either, files, email, firebug, etc.

Finally, try to minimize (if any) the use of "APPLICATION_ENV specific function, components, etc." use as in a real production environement, and use the provided tools (like Zend_Log, FirePHP, configuration tools, and mock object) if you want usefull debug informations.

---

Edit against your update:

Your solution is absolutely acceptable, even if you need to "repeat" x10. However, I'll go in slightly different way.

Something like that:

```
[production]
app.contacts.service1.name    = "Paul Dupont"
app.contacts.service1.email   = "paul.dupont@example.com"
app.contacts.service1.company = "Another Best Company"
app.contacts.service1.name  = "Kristina Dupuis"
app.contacts.service1.email = "k.dupuis@example.com"
[development]
app.contacts.service1.name    = "Me"
app.contacts.service1.email   = "me@example.com"
app.contacts.service1.company = "THE best company"
app.contacts.service1.name  = "Myself"
app.contacts.service1.email = "myself@example.com"
```

Right, it's a bit a heavy if you have a lot of service, but it's more more flexible than any hard-coded solution.

To use that, I'll go for:

1. [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), action helper are intended to be used only in Controller, easy, quick.
   **OR**
2. A domain model object through a Service, flexible, and config.ini update free (if more service why not store in database)

Both would have a similar skeleton

```
interface Service // Service means here the competent service of your company
{

public function getEmail() {}

public function getContactName() {}

public function getCompanyName() {}

}

// usage, somewhere in your code :
$this->request->setMethod('POST')
->setPost(array(
'name'    => $serviceService->getService('contactus')->getContactName(),
'email'   => $serviceService->getService('contactus')->getEmail(),
'message' => "This is my test message."
));
$this->dispatch('/about/contact');
```

Comment: Your answer seems a nice path to follow, however, I'm not sure if it could be adapted to my question update.

Comment: "I'd follow a simple principle: define a standard and only specify special cases when really needed.
E.g. "standard.email.address" that all forms could fall back to if there's no "specialform.email.address" defined.
When in development, only specify "standard.email.address" and you're done.

As on how to implement - I'd create an application resource, that handle's the address selection, e.g. "$resource->getAddressForForm('formName').
It lokks at the current config if there's a formName.email.address and returns that or the standard.
Simple thing, no overhead, target hit." Is this ok?

Comment: and All: What do you think about Zend_Config component ? Would that work on this described case? Thanks again.

Comment: That was a stupid comment. Using application.ini is using a Zend_Config component. bah! Btw, I'm using zend registry to register this config file. By doing this, we can then call zend registry staticly and access specific config params from anywhere on our application.